# Can't get dynamically created modal to close on click | opens with .parents()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a module that was built using a Handlebars.js template, I orignally had it opening and closing perfectly, but the information wasn't updated, this can be seen **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/9n2ax13v/embedded/result/)**.

Now I have it so it updates the info, but the toggleClass won't fire when clicking either the 'x' or .overlay. This can be seen **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/uqbh4y3m/93/embedded/result/)**.

Here is my jQuery functions to activate the modal.

```
 $(document).on('click', "a.btn", function (e) {
           $(e.target).parents('.image-container').prev('.modal').toggleClass('modal--show');
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.overlay', function (e) {
            $(e.target).prev('.modal').toggleClass('modal--show');
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.modal__close', function () {
            $('.modal').toggleClass('modal--show');
        });
```

How can I make it so this modal will both Open and Close, as well as display the correct information?

Some things I've tried...

- replacing: `$(e.target)` with `$(this)`

Comment: why don't use `$('.modal--show').removeClass('modal--show');`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are trying to toggle class of all `.modal` divs. But you need to toggle the class of only `.modal.modal--show`.
Also in case of overlay, you need to find the parent div not the sibling div. So use `.closest()` in place of `.prev()`

So if you modify your code as

```
        $(document).on('click', '.overlay', function (e) {
            $(e.target).closest('.modal.modal--show').toggleClass('modal--show');
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.modal__close', function () {
            $('.modal.modal--show').toggleClass('modal--show');
        });
```